# Problems with time travel debugger on elm-live

Tags: elm

I read the documentation for elm-live and discovered that I have to use `-- --debug` for it to work. I tried `elm-live src/Main.elm -- --debug` but it doesn't work even like that. I don't get any error messages or anything, the server just starts up normally but without the time travel debugger on. However, it works with elm make.

I tried both the stable version and the latest version of elm-live and updated node to its latest release but it doesn't work.

If it helps with anything I'm using the latest version of elm (0.19.1)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a limitation of Elm, not elm-live: if you execute

```
elm make src/Main.elm --debug
```

also you don't get the debugger.

I think that to get the debugger you need to use the compiler to create only the JS file, using the output argument:

```
--output=<output-file>
    Specify the name of the resulting JS file. For example
    --output=assets/elm.js to generate the JS at assets/elm.js or
    --output=/dev/null to generate no output at all!
```

For reference, this is the line that works for me:

```
elm-live src/Main.elm --start-page="index.html" --hot --dir=docs --port=8001 --path-to-elm=node_modules/.bin/elm -- --output="docs/js-compiled/elm.js" --debug
```

Comment: I think I was clear about the fact using "elm make src/Main.elm --debug" does in fact work. But thanks for the reference. I'll try it out.